# Can I automatically make my Nvidia card's fan quieter?

Tags: nvidia

I have a machine with an Nvidia graphics card. Unfortunately the GPU fan is very loud. It's very annoying at times.

We never use this machine for intense 3d work - that GPU is probably not working very hard at all. I'm pretty sure I can run it at a much lower fan-speed without causing any problems.

The nvclock utility can be used to manually adjust the fan-speed of my Nvidia graphics card. I'd like to call this utility automatically when the machine boots up.

Is there some kind of system service which I can use to automatically apply this kind of system-wide configuration? Even better, is there a system monitoring service which can poll the GPU temperature and adjust the various system fan-speeds accordingly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, use `/etc/rc.local` to place commands intended to run at boot.

You can also use an `xorg.conf` trick to permanently lock the GPU and graphical memory clocks to their lowest values.

```
gksudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

add the following to the Device Section:

```
Option  "RegistryDwords" "PerfLevelSrc=0x2222; PowerMizerDefault=0x3; PowerMizerDefaultAC=0x3"
```

If the file is empty or there is no device section, here is an example of mine:

```
Section "Device"
Identifier  "Default Device"
Option  "NoLogo"    "True"
Option  "RegistryDwords" "PerfLevelSrc=0x2222; PowerMizerDefault=0x3; PowerMizerDefaultAC=0x3"
EndSection
```

For more info on various Nvidia related options, check out http://tutanhamon.com.ua/technovodstvo/NVIDIA-UNIX-driver/

The original page has not been available for some years, so I'll link to it in the [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20100204031206/http://tutanhamon.com.ua/technovodstvo/NVIDIA-UNIX-driver)